# Set Android Timezone/time info from firmware

Tags: android, linux, time, timezone, zone

I'm working on a project with a no-name android box, and the default setting for the time zone is some place in China. I would like to arrange the firmware in such a way so I can set it to always go with Eastern time, because changing it back every time I do a flash is getting annoying.

I tried looking for `/etc/localtime` but that is not there.  `/usr/share/zoneinfo` only has 3 files in it, `zoneinfo.dat`, `zoneinfo.idx`, and `zoneinfo.version`. None of them offer any help.

So how can I set the time zone in Android from the firmware files?

Comment: Or can anyone tell me how to change the timezone without going in to settings and doing it?